# JMeter test on Netty-based impl produces error for every second request

Tags: java, jmeter, netty

I've implemented an HTTP service based on the [HTTP server example](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/helloworld) as provided by the netty.io project.

When I execute a GET request to the service URL from command-line (wget) or from a browser, I receive a result as expected.

When I perform a load test using ApacheBench `ab -n 100000 -c 8 http://localhost:9000/path/to/service`, experience no errors (neither on service nor on ab side) and see fair numbers for request processing duration.

Afterwards, I set up a test plan in JMeter having a thread group with 1 thread and a loop count of 2. I inserted an HTTP request sampler where I simply added the server name `localhost`, the port number `9000` and the path `/path/to/service`. Then I also added a `View Results Tree` and a `Summary Report` listener.

Finally, I executed the test plan and received one valid response and one error showing the following content:

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2015-06-04 09:23:12 CEST
Load time: 0
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 2068
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 2068
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: The target server failed to respond

Response headers:


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

The associated exception found in response data tab showed the following content

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:61)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.receiveResponseHeader(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:201)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:715)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:520)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:517)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:331)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1135)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:434)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

As I have a similar service already running which receives and processes web tracking data which shows no errors, it might be a problem within my test plan or JMeter .. but I am not sure :-(

Did anyone experience similar behavior? Thanks in advance ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue can be related to Keep-Alive management.

Read those:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57921
- https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed

So your solution is one of those:

If you're sure it's a keep alive issue:

- Try jmeter nightly build http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html:

  ```
  Download the _bin and _lib files
  Unpack the archives into the same directory structure
  The other archives are not needed to run JMeter.
  ```
- And adapt the value of httpclient4.idletimeout

A workaround is to increase retry or add connection stale check as per :

- https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed